# Use django - admin functions in non admin template

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to use django - admin functions in non admin template. I mean using only functions, for example, add, update and delete info in models. How can I use it? Or i have to create own functions?

Answer (score 0):

You should read the Django documentation. This topic guide from the djangoproject, will tell you how to make queries, such as adding, updating and deleting objects.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/

Comment: No, you do not understand my question. I have table with Pictures. And user has to edit this table. So I want to extend admin functions.